# Get highligted text from embed

Tags: javascript, html, embed

Im trying to get the highlighted text of a embeded window. Essentialy i want to go on a website, say weather.gov, highlight some snipper of text and get what ive highlighted in JS.

Does anyone have any insight into doing this?

```
<embed id="myFrame" src="http://www.weather.gov/" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px" allowScriptAccess="always"/>
<script>
function GetSelectedData() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    var data = doc.window.getSelection();

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, But it is ***not*** Possible to use getSelection Method in any other Object Than window itself.

And window object can't be created inside a document object.